# Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library give me redirect_url_mismatch

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I am trying to integrate with  Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library by getting the authorize code then go to back end to ask for access token and refresh token for that code

my code on vue

```
const googleProvider = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
    client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
    ux_mode: 'popup',
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8000/auth/socialite/callback",
    callback: (response) => {
        alert('dasd')
        console.log(response)
        client.requestAccessTokenWithCode(response.code, {
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/auth/socialite/callback', // Specify your redirect URI
        }).then((response) => {
        console.log('Access token:', response.access_token);
        }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error getting access token:', err);
        });
    },
});
```

my code on laravel to issue refresh token and access token

```
 try {
            $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ])->post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', [
                'grant_type'                    =>  "authorization_code",
                'code'                          =>  '4/0AfJohXnHrMWalZybmFOPgrQXRcKjgyNpBod8SbTPOpuHMn04OyVKrUxQUMsqTwtD4v1F_g',
                'client_id'                     =>  env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret'                 =>  env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'redirect_uri'                  =>  "http://localhost:8000/auth/socialite/callback",
            ]);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            dd($th);
        }

        dd($response->json());
```

but i am keeping getting redirect_url_mismatch error on laravel when i am trying to issue refresh and access token